# playwright generates iframe that is blocking pointers

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, playwright

I have this project that DOES NOT use iframes yet my test fails because `<iframe></iframe> intercepts pointer events`.

Note that this happens 50% of the time whenever I run my test. I do not see any iframes popping when test succeeds

I ran some debugs and found out that playwright is making an iframe and thats the one blocking the pointer events. I'm totally lost on how to fix this one. perhaps any ideas?

error logs

```
locator.click: Target closed
=========================== logs ===========================
waiting for getByRole('button', { name: 'ArrType ​' })
  locator resolved to <div tabindex="0" role="button" id="ArrTypeInput" ar…>…</div>
attempting click action
  waiting for element to be visible, enabled and stable
  element is visible, enabled and stable
  scrolling into view if needed
  done scrolling
  <iframe></iframe> intercepts pointer events
retrying click action, attempt #1
  waiting for element to be visible, enabled and stable
  element is visible, enabled and stable
  scrolling into view if needed
  done scrolling
  <iframe></iframe> intercepts pointer events
retrying click action, attempt #2
  waiting 20ms
  waiting for element to be visible, enabled and stable
  element is visible, enabled and stable
  scrolling into view if needed
  done scrolling
  <iframe></iframe> intercepts pointer events
retrying click action, attempt #3
  waiting 100ms
  waiting for element to be visible, enabled and stable
  element is visible, enabled and stable
  scrolling into view if needed
  done scrolling
  <iframe></iframe> intercepts pointer events
retrying click action, attempt #4
  waiting 100ms
  waiting for element to be visible, enabled and stable
  element is visible, enabled and stable
  scrolling into view if needed
  done scrolling
  <iframe></iframe> intercepts pointer events
retrying click action, attempt #5
  waiting 500ms
  waiting for element to be visible, enabled and stable
  element is visible, enabled and stable
  scrolling into view if needed
  done scrolling
  <iframe></iframe> intercepts pointer events
retrying click action, attempt #6
  waiting 500ms
  waiting for element to be visible, enabled and stable
  element is visible, enabled and stable
  scrolling into view if needed
  done scrolling
  <iframe></iframe> intercepts pointer events
retrying click action, attempt #7
  waiting 500ms
  waiting for element to be visible, enabled and stable
  element is visible, enabled and stable
  scrolling into view if needed
  done scrolling
  <iframe></iframe> intercepts pointer events
retrying click action, attempt #8
  waiting 500ms
============================================================

  125 |         
  126 |
> 127 |         await page.getByRole('button', { name: 'ArrType ​' }).click();
```

[The Iframe in question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tbms5.png)

project is using react @mui/material for front-end

tried downgrading from latest to something like 1.2X but didn't fixed anything.